# Split string at '+'

Tags: r, strsplit

I have a coordinate in the following format:

```
coordinate <- "43.12+332.11"
```

Since I need to recover individual Latitude and Longitude parts of this coordinate, I wanted to split at the '+'.

Running the following code:

```
splitted <- strsplit(coordinate,'+')
```

however gave this result:

```
[[1]]
[1] "4" "3" "." "1" "2" "+" "3" "3" "2" "." "1" "1"
```

How can I split this string at the '+'?

Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: try splitting on `"[+]"`

Comment: You need to escape it, or use `fixed = TRUE`(prefered)

Comment: strsplit(coordinate, "+", fixed = TRUE)

Comment: @BigSecrect Hi, if this solves the Problem can you promote your comment to a solution so that the OP can mark it as such? Thanks.